# Japanese filename being read as 8.3 on Windows

Tags: perl, encoding

I'm working on a Windows system with Perl 5.8.8 (yes, it's old but it's what's on the server and I can't change that).

I've been sent a csv datafile from our Japan office.  The filename is 'a151110a（01_WeLBA①）.csv'.  My perl script can open and read the file, but it sees the filename as 'A15111~1.CSV'; so it's interpreting the filename into 8.3 format.  I've tried using `glob` and `readdir` to create a file list and both give the same result.

The problem is that I need to be able to pull some info out of the filename.  I need that part that is inside the parentheses, the '01_WeLBA' part.  But Perl doesn't seem to "see" that.  Those parentheses have a space (or other whitespace character) either in front or just after them.  If I manually remove those and that numeral '1'-inside-a-circle character, then Perl sees the filename as it is.

Is there a way to get Perl to 'see' the filename as it appears in Windows Explorer?

Comment: [Win32::LongPath](http://p3rl.org/Win32::LongPath)?

Comment: This is a long standing Perl bug, going back two decades (oneperl). This should have been fixed years ago, but Win32 people with tuits and focus are in short supply.

Comment: @choroba - That worked!  Post it as an answer and I'll accept it!  Using opendirL, readdirL, and renameL did what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Win32::LongPath](http://p3rl.org/Win32::LongPath), it does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Win32::LongPath](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::LongPath)'s `opendirL`, `readdirL` and `closedirL`.

---

Windows provides two versions of each system call that accepts strings:

- The "UNICODE" version (suffixed with "W" for "wide") accepts/returns strings encoded using UTF-16le. This version supports all Unicode characters.
- The "ANSI" version (suffixed with "A") accepts/returns strings encoded using the Active Code Page (ACP). The "A" version only supports a small subset of the Unicode characters.

  You can obtain the ACP for your system using the following:

  ```
  perl -Mv5.14 -MWin32 -e"say Win32::GetACP()"
  ```

Unfortunately, Perl functions (named operators) use the "A" version of system calls and expect/return text encoded using the ACP. This severely limits which file names that can be passed to them.

For example, my system's ACP is [1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), so the "A" version of system calls would not support Japanese characters. This means there is nothing I can do to make `open`, `-e`, etc work with file names containing Japanese characters. ouch.

Win32::LongPath provides alternatives to Perl's builtins that use the "W" version of system calls, and thus support all Unicode characters. For example, `-e` is just a call to `stat`, and it provides `statL`.